# CSS Won't align <li>

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I want to set list in header section but everytime I do, my home, about and blog goes out of background color or background color minimize. I dont know how much you can understand me what i want to say if you want i can put picture where i want list to be.

```css
header {
  background: #304852;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: #585858 3px solid;
}

header a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 40px;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="logo">

    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/60/" width="120px" height="60px">
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>

      <li><a href="C:\Users\Mihajlo\Desktop\retardirani mihajlo\Web about">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="C:\Users\Mihajlo\Desktop\retardirani mihajlo\Web about">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li> <a href="C:\Users\Mihajlo\Desktop\retardirani mihajlo\Web about">BLOG</a></li>
      <li><a href="C:\Users\Mihajlo\Desktop\retardirani mihajlo\Web about">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: What do you mean "It goes out of the background color" are you saying that the list-items are displaying in-line rather than on one line? Also, please post your HTML code.

Comment: Yes please put a picture and also use lorempixel or placeholder to generate images. I put your CSS where it belonged in the snippet

Answer (score 0):

The best course of action would be to remove the `float` from your `header li` and `header nav` CSS selectors, and instead apply a simple `text-align` to `header nav`.

See the attached code for reference.

```css
header{
  background: #304852;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: #585858 3px solid;
}
header a{
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 40px;
}
header ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header li{
  /* float: left; */
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header nav{
  /* float: right; */
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you soo much i was working on this problems for 3 hours im soo thankful

Comment: My pleasure, mi amigo! If that worked for you, please upvote my answer and accept the response.

Answer (score 0):

Two changes necessary:

1.) `float: left;` on `#logo` , since other wise it's a block element and takes the whole width.

2.) `overflow: auto` on `header`, since it then only contains floated elements and wouldn't keep the background color.

```css
header {
  background: #304852;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: #585858 3px solid;
  overflow: auto;
}

header a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="logo">

    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/60/" width="120px" height="60px">
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>

      <li><a href="C:\Users\Mihajlo\Desktop\retardirani mihajlo\Web about">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="C:\Users\Mihajlo\Desktop\retardirani mihajlo\Web about">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li> <a href="C:\Users\Mihajlo\Desktop\retardirani mihajlo\Web about">BLOG</a></li>
      <li><a href="C:\Users\Mihajlo\Desktop\retardirani mihajlo\Web about">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```